# Google Vision API OCR - Not recognizing Arabic well

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

**Background**

I am using google vision ocr on this input image:

[image]

Expected text:

> التَّمْكِينُ الاقْتِصَادِيُّ لِلَّاجِئِينَ السُّورِيِّينَ

Vision api response text:

> ا ل ت م ك ي ن ا ل ا ق ت ص ا د ي ل ل ا ج ئ ي ن ا ل ش و ر ي ي ن

Used the Vision Api try it now to validate this:
[image]

**Problems**

1. Between each letter there are spaces
2. Vowelization characters are missing(the small symbols above/below the letters)

**Question**

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can click the Show JSON option from the page and it will show you the JSON response of the request:

[image]

[image]

I recommend you to try this documentation as well [3](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#detect_text_in_a_local_image) so you could test the Vision API using your preferred programming language for advanced integrations.

Comment: Got what you were saying, thanks. This solves the spaces problem. Extracted Text: "wالتمكين الاقتصادي للاجئين الشوريين". But still what can I do with the vowelization characters missing.

Comment: I was able to extract the vowels by following the documentation I provided above so I really recommended trying it:

       "text": "التَّمْكِينُ الاقُصَِادِ لِلَّاحِئِيِنَ السُّورِيِّنَ\n.....\n"

The result might be affected since this is a demo page:

The text detection feature used in this demo is DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION. Results from this feature may differ from results returned from a TEXT_DETECTION feature request.